# Express js/Handlebars newbie - Using res.locals.currentPost only works in some cases and cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, ill try my best to describe my issue.

I am working on a image website project (think imgur/flickr) and am using handlebars templating for the first time. I've made a page to view individual photos with the photo info (who posted it and description) and a comments section. The comments section works perfectly but the photo and photo info wont load.

I have been trying for hours and I cannot figure out why its only working for one and not the other. I wrote error codes to follow the info and it does make it to the middleware needed for the page but doesn't appear on the page.

Here is my code for the middleware page:

```
var {getMRecentPosts, getMPostById} = require('../models/Posts');
const {getCommentsForPost} = require('../models/Comments');
const { errorPrint, successPrint } = require('../helpers/debug/debugprinters');
const postMW = {};

postMW.getPostById = async function (req, res, next) {
    try{
        successPrint(req.params.id);
        let results =  await getMPostById(req.params.id);

        successPrint(results[0]);

        if(results && results.length){
            res.locals.currentPost = results[0];
            errorPrint(res.locals.currentPost);
            next();
        }else{
            req.flash("error", "This is not the post you are looking for.");
            res.redirect('/');
        }   
    }catch(error){
        next(error);
    }
}

postMW.getCommentsByPostId = async function (req, res, next) {
    try{
        let results = await getCommentsForPost(req.params.id);
        res.locals.currentPost.comments = results;
        next();
    }catch (error){
        next(error);
    }
}

module.exports = postMW;
```

Here is the console message from my errorPrinter (again there's no actual system error just trying to make sure the info is making it this far):

```
[
  BinaryRow {
    username: 'dan',
    title: 'Flying fox back at it again',
    description: 'Once a gain not actually a fox, just called on',
    photopath: 'public\\images\\uploads\\3404ba6eb264c819ff7011378b756c8426c17e4d57bc.jpeg',
    created: 2020-12-20T00:28:28.000Z
  }
]
```

Here is my code for the Hbs file:

```
<div id="post-container">
    <div id="photo-container">
        <div id="post-title" class="display-6 font-weight-bold">{{currentPost.title}}</div>
        <div id="post-info">
            <p><span class="form-label">Posted by:</span>
                <span id="post-author">
                    {{currentPost.username}}
                </p>
            <p><span class="form-label">Posted at:</span><span id="post-date">{{currentPost.created}}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="post-description" class="lead">{{currentPost.description}}</div>
        <img id="post-image" class="img-fluid" src="/{{currentPost.photopath}}" alt="A photo should have been here">
    </div>

    <div id="comment-container">
        <div id="messages">
            {{#each currentPost.comments}}
            {{> comment this}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div id="comment-box">
            <textarea id="comment-box-text" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"
                placeholder="Enter Comment Here!"></textarea>
            <span id="comment-box-button" class="input-group-text"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/ffffff/paper-plane.png"/></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any insight is welcome!!! I'm so blind to what the error is and/or I'm just really bad at googling for correct help lol